# (Laravel & Nginx) CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘(null)’

Tags: nginx, cors, laravel-5.5

I have SPA which located at localhost:8080 and an API at dev.mywebsite, both are running on local server. I tried to use ajax but it returned 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' twice, screenshot attached. I have no idea why this happen.

[image]

Below is my nginx configuration:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    # Port
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # Server Name
    server_name dev.narpandi;

    # Logging
    rewrite_log on;

    # Location of public directory
    root /var/www/personal-website/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

    # Remove trailing slash to please routing system
    if (!-d $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

          set $cors "";

          if ($http_origin ~* 'http://localhost:8080')
          {
            set $cors "true";
          }

          if ($cors = 'true')
          {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Pragma,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With';
          }

          #if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS')
          #{
            #return 204;
          #}
    }

    # Disable all htaccess
    location ~ /\.ht {
      deny all;
    }
}
```

Did I miss something? Thank you for your help.

**-Edited-**

Decided to remove Nginx CORS configuration and use `barryvdh/laravel-cors` because you can specify which routes have CORS by adding middleware.

Here is my code:

**config/cors.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['http://yourwebsite.com'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
];
```

**app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class Cors
{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  }
}
```

**app/Http/Kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
  ...
  'cors' => \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class
];
```

And finally use it in your routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'about', 'middleware' => [ ..., 'cors']],  function(){ 
  ...
});
```

Thank you for the help and sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using both `NGINX` cors and `barryvdh/laravel-cors`. Both create a header.

Delete the `NGINX` one should work.

Comment: When using a stack of several technologies, I'd suggest that the outmost should be taking care of communication with the outside world. Thus, I'd consider leaving nginx to manage CORS and removing the corresponding logic from Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your application is setting CORS headers as well. You need to eliminate one.

Nginx combines duplicate headers into one header separated by a comma. That's what you are getting and that's normal behavior of Nginx.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I remove `barryvdh/laravel-cors` package from my application, but the header changed into `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*, http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: something else is setting CORS headers, remove that too.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have to restart my notebook several times because it randomly freezing. In the end, I decided to remove `barryvdh/laravel-cors` package completely (the last time I comment, some cors configuration are still there so the issue persist).